# php form check box value getting error

Tags: php, html

i can't find the error 
every thing ok expect check box value not getting as list

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $hobby_temp = $_POST['hobby'];
    $size = count($hobby_temp);
    for($i = 0; $i < size; $i++)
    {
        $hobby=$hobby.','.$hobby_temp[$i];
    }
    echo 'Name:'.$fname.'<br>';
    echo 'age:'.$age.'<br>';
    echo 'comment:'.$comment.'<br>';
    echo 'gender:'.$gender.'<br>';
    echo 'Hobbies:'.$hobby.'<br>';
}
?>
```

note : every thing display expect hobbies

Comment: Hobbies: 
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="1"/>Stamp collecting
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="2"/>Fish 
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="3"/>other
  <br/><br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
$hobby=$hobby.','.$hobby_temp[$i];
```

It should be

```
$hobby = "" //initialize outside the loop
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
    if($i==0) $hobby = $hobby_temp[$i];
    else $hobby = $hobby .', '.hobby_temp[$i] ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much i found issue $hobby = "" //initialize outside the loop and in loop i have miss $ mark for(..$size..) other than code working eg  $hobby = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `$hobby` at each loop, instead you should concatenate your variable

```
$hobby = '';
for($i = 0; $i < size; $i++)
{
    $hobby .= $hobby_temp[$i] . ',';
}
$hobby = substr_replace($hobby, '', -1);
```

Comment: This will leave a trailing ,

Comment: Thanks you very much i found issue $hobby = "" //initialize outside the loop and in the loop i have miss $ mark size variable  for(..$size..) other than code working eg $hobby = ''; for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)

Answer (score 0):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$hobby = isset($_POST["hobby"])?implode(",",$_POST["hobby"]):"");
```